# What do the egit merge modes mean?

Tags: eclipse, git, egit, jgit

I am doing a rebase with egit and there is a conflict egit popus up the following dialog box
[image]

It is not clear to me what these two options. My questions are.

- What do these options really mean?
- Under what circumstances would I choose one option over the other?
- Which HEAD does head refer to the HEAD of the branch I am rebasing on or the head of the branch I am rebasing?
- What do these merge modes correspond to in the command line version of egit?

Comment: what exactly were you doing to get this message? I mean, what branch did you want to rebase?

Comment: just rebasing a local feature branch on top of master which is about 4 commits ahead of the feature branch. When a conflict is detected during rebase egit asks if you want to start the merge tool if you say yes it gives the dialog box above.

Comment: The bad news is that the question makes no sense at all.  But the good news is that you check the box to never be asked again!

Comment: With EGit 3.4, the dialog will no longer be shown (by default) and HEAD will be used, see [bug 431127](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=431127).

Answer (score 6):

The different modes are specific to Eclipse, and have no corresponding merge mode in command line. The difference between the modes is the following:

1. If you use the workspace version, an editor will open with a single file containing all elements (both added and removed) in a single file, as the default git merge would do it. This is useful if there is no compare editor available for your file type.
2. Using HEAD you can get a compare editor, where both your branches and the merged branches HEADS are displayed side-by-side, allowing merging using the Eclipse compare editor.

As I am using EGit with Java projects, the HEAD version option makes more sense to me; I believe, the other option is only there for some very specific reasons.